# C++ Hermite polynomial implementation

Tags: c++, polynomial-math, hermite

Can anyone recommend a good numerical library providing a C++ implementation of Hermite polynomials? I am building them brute force, using iterative algorithms, but I would like some ready made alternatives which will probably work more quickly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't mind using Boost, there is a Hermite polynomial implementation in `boost/math/special_functions/hermite.hpp`

Check out the docs here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/math/doc/html/math_toolkit/sf_poly/hermite.html

Answer (score 3):

The Boost libraries have a ready made set of functions for Hermite Polynomials.

```
#include <boost/math/special_functions/hermite.hpp>
```

I've never used this boost header but you can start reading about it here:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/math/doc/sf_and_dist/html/math_toolkit/special/sf_poly/hermite.html